# How to add labels to points in elevation plot in R?

Tags: raster, r, sp

I am a complete noob at using GIS in R and have been trying many packages and functions but get stuck each time. What I want is to generate an elevation map for a location in the Himalayas with additional geographic points that are labeled, and possibly rivers.

What I have so far is the following code that retrieves elevation data and does some basic plotting:

```r
    library(elevatr)
    library(raster)

    #set  projection
    prj4<-"+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

    # set plot bounds
    bounds <- data.frame(x=c(85.8,87.4),y=c(26.6,28.2))

    # retrieve elevation raster
    elev<-get_elev_raster(locations = bounds, 
                          prj = prj4,
                          z=9, 
                          clip="locations")

    plot(elev)

    # Add two dots
    dotcoords<-data.frame(x = c(86.3,87.1), y = c(27.2,27.8))
    rownames(dotcoords)<-c("locA","locB")
    coordinates(dotcoords) <- c("x","y")
    proj4string(dotcoords) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") 
    pts_dotcoords <- spTransform(dotcoords, CRS(prj4))

    plot(pts_dotcoords, add=T, pch=16)
```

This generates the following plot:[image: elevation_plot]
**My question is how I can add labels to the dots showing the associated names ("locA" and "locB")?**

This is probably basic stuff but I really need some advice on what approach to take to get me going in the right direction (would it be better to use ggplot2 or ggmap, for example?).

Comment: Thanks for your directions. I have edited my post accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After plotting the the points you need to call `text()`:

```
plot(elev)
plot(pts_dotcoords, add = TRUE, pch = 16)    
text(pts_dotcoords, labels = c("locA", "locB"), pos = 4, offset = 0.7)
```

[image: R plot]

See also `?text`:

> `pos`: a position specifier for the text.  If specified this
>         overrides any `adj` value given.  Values of ‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’ and
>         ‘4’, respectively indicate positions below, to the left of,
>         above and to the right of the specified coordinates.
>
> `offset`: when `pos` is specified, this value gives the offset of the
>            label from the specified coordinate in fractions of a
>            character width.